# How can we get playstore app version in ionic 3 application?

Tags: html, json, typescript, ionic3, angular4-httpclient

I have tried so many solutions from google, but no any luck, I didn't get proper solution. How can i get app version from Playstore?

Answer (score 0):

You can't get app version from Playstore, If you want to get your app version in your code so you need to use this plugin [App Version](https://ionicframework.com/docs/v3/native/app-version/)